# How to solve this particular task about centroids

Tags: calculus, integration, centroid

[image]

Can anyone help me with 29.I know how to find centroids when one function is given but in this one I don't think that knowing only the function of circle or rectangle will help us.I found that there is something called additive centroids but I don't know how that one works here.Can anyone fully explain this task and additive centroids please?

Comment: Centroids are averages. Get the centroid for each piece and then take the average of their coordinates. By symmetry this amounts to taking the average of the $y$ values from each individual centroid.

Comment: Ohh really...I did not know that, but where does it come from?I think there should be a proof for that

Comment: Look into the derivation of the centroid. It extends from a weighted average of discrete points in space to an integral.

Comment: Honestly,I could not understand your point...

Comment: I just want a solid proof that average can be found when we talk about unit shapes like the one given above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can probably guess (by symmetry or intuition), the centroid of the rectangle is at $C_1 =(0,h/2)$. Now the centroid of semicircle is actually $\frac{4r}{3\pi}$ above the centre of the circle which in our case makes it

$$C_2 = (0,h+\frac{4a}{3\pi})$$

To calculate the centroid of the entire figure you simply use weighted averages

$$C = \frac{C_1\cdot 2ah + C_2\cdot\pi r^2}{2ah+\pi r^2}$$

You can take it from here, I believe.

Reference - http://datagenetics.com/blog/january52017/index.html

Comment: Huge thanks for great answer.One more thing,it is the first time that I encounter term weighted averages, What does it mean in general?Can that formula be applied to all kind of united shapes?

Comment: As you see I am reading this lesson from the book and there was nothing about this term

Comment: A normal or non-weighted average is where you sum everything up and divide by the total number. However, in a weighted average, every quantity has a different weight and each value is multiplied by its weight and then divided by the sum of weights.

Reference - https://math.tutorvista.com/statistics/weighted-average.html

Comment: Also could you please accept the answer then?

Comment: Got it finally.Huge thanks